# Can store bought honey be used to infuse garlic and honey?

Tags: fermentation, garlic, honey

The only question I could find about honey infused garlic on the site was [Honey-fermented garlic left open overnight](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/96939/honey-fermented-garlic-left-open-overnight) but they do not mention what type of Honey they use. From my research I've read:

- [DIY: Immune Boosting Honey Infused Garlic](https://dontwastethecrumbs.com/diy-immune-boosting-honey-infused-garlic/)
- [Fermented Garlic Honey](https://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/fermented-garlic-honey)

but I have a lot of leftover varieties of honey and I was thinking about making fermented honey since I was gifted fresh garlic and I would use this when the recipe called for a garlic clove.

Comment: honey might be antimicrobial, but unless you get an authoritative source and instructions specifically on how to prepare the garlic, I'd be *really* wary of this being a new and exciting way to get botulism.  (and I'm not usually one to worry about other risky food behavior)

Comment: I do remember about botulism when I was learning about sous vide. No signs point to it from my research.

Comment: I would note that in recent years, cases of botulism (admittedly quite a rare disease) have been caused by (a) garlic and (b) honey. (Not sure why you looked it up in the context of sous vide, it's not really a concern there.)

Comment: @Sneftel I learned about it when there were reports of botulism with raw garlic in vacuum sealed bags doing SV

Comment: There is a reason why *you don't give honey to infants*. A few facts: 1) *Clostridium botulinum* is a strictly anaerobic bacteria that pops out of their spores when put in a low-to-none oxygen environment. When the bacteria erupts out of the spore, it produces the botulism toxin; 2) Honey is very resistant to bacterial proliferation due to low water availability. That means that the bacteria in there die quickly, but the point #1 is not conditioned to the bacteria being still alive. Even when the bacteria dies the toxin is still there.

Comment: Juliana, that should be an answer