How to ensure oil tastes like tomato?
So I mixed and fried some tomatoes with tallow and really liked the taste. Tomatoes seem to be very potent at changing a fats flavour.
So I tried to do the same with extra virgin olive oil and notice I can still taste the olive oil at times even though I had used a lot of tomatoes but I probably fried for less time around 8 minutes which I imagine is still a lot.
Just wanting to know what factors determine how well the tomatoes will change the taste of the oil? I used a lot of tomatoes but that didn’t seem to ensure the olive oil taste was completely gone. Do I need to do it for longer ie more frying of tomatoes the evo will taste more like tomatoes or if the tomatoes have melted after 8 minutes should that be enough and further frying won’t make the oil taste more like tomatoes?
Or is there something about olive oil that always makes it taste like olive oil even when cooked?  I doubt this because when I previously cooked a soup with a few ingredients including olive oil and tomatoes and the evos strong taste had completely gone.
Thanks

I don't really know how to answer your question, thus the comment rather than an answer but I did just want to mention that there is a risk of botulism when making infused oils. So I'd strongly advise against keeping your tomato oil for any longer than a week in the fridge. See this answer for more info (which whilst focused on the use of garlic, also directly applies to tomatoes) - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/101262/can-store-bought-honey-be-used-to-infuse-garlic-and-honey/128403#128403

If your goal is an oil with tomato flavor I would start with a mostly flavorless oil, so maybe canola oil or sunflower seed oil but not olive oil unless you want the flavor of the olive oil.
